# Parallax effect works in browser but not in mobile

Tags: html, css

I have added a parallax effect to my image gallery section in my website. The effect works great in normal desktop and responsive mode in the browsers. However, when I try to view the same in my mobile (iPhone 6), the background in the section does not stay fixed, but rather extends for the whole content of that section , making the background very zoomed in and pixelated.

This my html :

```
<section id="projects">
        <div class="parallax">
            <div class="container" style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 class="section-header-inverse wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="200ms" data-wow-duration="500ms">Our Projects</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="gallery">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                                <a href="www/images/projects/500x500.png"><img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x250/ffffff" alt="" title="Beautiful Image" /></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                                <a href="www/images/projects/750x500.png"><img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x250/ffffff" alt="" title="" /></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                                <a href="www/images/projects/600x300.png"><img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x250/ffffff" alt="" title="Beautiful Image" /></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                                <a href="www/images/projects/900x800.png"><img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x250/ffffff" alt="" title="" /></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                                <a href="www/images/projects/500x500.png"><img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x250/ffffff" alt="" title="Beautiful Image" /></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                                <a href="www/images/projects/750x500.png"><img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x250/ffffff" alt="" title="" /></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                                <a href="www/images/projects/600x300.png"><img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x250/ffffff" alt="" title="Beautiful Image" /></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                                <a href="www/images/projects/900x800.png"><img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x250/ffffff" alt="" title="" /></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                                <a href="www/images/projects/500x500.png"><img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x250/ffffff" alt="" title="Beautiful Image" /></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                                <a href="www/images/projects/750x500.png"><img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x250/ffffff" alt="" title="" /></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                                <a href="www/images/projects/600x300.png"><img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x250/ffffff" alt="" title="Beautiful Image" /></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                                <a href="www/images/projects/900x800.png"><img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x250/ffffff" alt="" title="" /></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

This is the css for this section :

```
#projects {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}


/*Project Section CSS*/

.parallax {
    background-image: url('../images/backgrounds/bg.jpg');
    /* Set a specific height */
    /*height: 600px;*/
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.gallery img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.gallery .row {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .gallery .thumbnail {
        padding-bottom: 7px;
    }
}

.gallery .thumbnail {
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}

.gallery .thumbnail:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    -o-transform: scale(1.05);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
    transition: all 150ms ease-in;
}
```

I even tried to add vendor prefixes to the properties. But still it does not work. Please help me to get this working as expected.

The website can be accessed [here](https://srsconstructions.herokuapp.com/#projects)

Comment: `background-attachement: fixed` is not supported on iOS, sorry.

Comment: is there any other way ?

Comment: Not that I know of, maybe create an element that is fixed position, this would be behind the section you want the image to appear behind.

Comment: I’ve run into the exact same issue in the past, and the only cross-device solution I found to work well enough to be deployed live was (sadly) to serve downsized images based on media queries.
Essentially I had to create Full Size, Half Size, and Quarter Sizes for all the Parallax backgrounds, and then depending on the device screen width serve the most appropriate solution.

Comment: @GmaSa so you created three images width three different widths for mobile, tablet and desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I am showing an example which works on every devices i.e. IPhone, IPad, Android, windows. The Methodology is different as you can see.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Parallax</title>
</head>

<style>
.section-one {
position:relative;
height:662px;
}

.section-one:before {
content:'';
background:blue url('2.jpg') no-repeat;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
</style>

<body>
<section class="section-one"></section>
</body>
</html>
```